# Show table onclick button - jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Employee table in SQL with 3 columns - EmployeeID (identity), EmployeeName and BossID . If an employee is a Boss, their BossID is -1. For example if John is a boss and his EmployeeID is 12 , his workers have 12 as their BossID while John's is -1.

I want to show 2 tables, The Bosses Table and the workers table (after clicking on an specific boss row to get their ID and only show that boss's workers)

Heres my code below :

-Controller

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {

        EmployeeModule EM = new EmployeeModule();



        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.List1 = EM.ListEmployees1();
            ViewBag.List2 = TempData["List2"];
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult List2(int id)
        {



            TempData["List2"] = EM.ListEmployees2(id);

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
        }
    }
```

ListEmployees1 Method returns the Employee List where their BossID = -1 (Boss Table)
and ListEmployees2 returns the Employee List given an id (Workers Table)

-Index.cshtml

```
   div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">


                           -- Boss Table

                            <tbody>
                             @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.List1)
                             {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  id=@item.ID ><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>@item.EmployeeID</td>
                                        <td>@item.EmployeeName</td>
                                        <td>@item.BossID</td>
                                     </tr>
                             }
                            </tbody>


                        </table>

                    </div>



                </section>




           </div>








        </div>

        @if (@ViewBag.List2 != null) { 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">





                              --Workers Table





                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.List2)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.EmployeeID</td>
                                        <td>@item.EmployeeName</td>
                                        <td>@item.BossID</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>


                        </table>

                    </div>



                </section>




            </div>








        </div>
        }

    </div>



script>
   $('button[type="button"]').on('click', function (e)
    {



            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url : "@Url.Action("List2", "Employee")" + "?id=" + id,

                success: function () {
                    window.location.href="/Employee/Index"
                }


            })



   });
</script>
```

When i click the button to show the workers table , it calls The List2 action but when it goes to Index , it doesnt show it .

Comment: try to use the bootstrap panel, first render the the parent and then render the child.

Comment: this was just examplet: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/6JyFr/4/

Comment: first you can render the parent grid in first panel then render the child panel with there grid and just use the normal process you don't need the jquery for that.